# Twilio awaits response, I don't want server to respond

Tags: ruby, twilio, webhooks

I am using a Slack webhook to process incoming SMS messages from Twilio. However, the way I have it set up, It seems that Twilio is expecting the web server (slack) to respond to it. This causes errors to be generated in Twilio, and I obviously don't want errors because I'll be getting emails.

I am using the `twilio-ruby` gem in Ruby to send out the SMS messages, and using the `slack-ruby-client` to monitor incoming messages from Slack.

How do I stop Twilio from trying to expect a response from the web server when it POSTS to the Slack webhook? Is that even possible or do I have this all configured incorrectly?

**EDIT**

Here's the function that I have which sends the forwarded SMS to Slack:

```
const https = require("https");

// Make sure to declare SLACK_WEBHOOK_PATH in your Environment
// variables at
// https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/functions/configure

exports.handler = (context, event, callback) => {
  // Extract the bits of the message we want
  const { To, From, Body } = event;

  // Construct a payload for slack's incoming webhooks
  const slackBody = JSON.stringify({
        text: `!asi SMS\nFrom: ${From}\nMessage: ${Body}`
  });

  // Form our request specification
  const options = {
    host: "hooks.slack.com",
    port: 443,
    path: context.SLACK_WEBHOOK_PATH,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Content-Length": slackBody.length
    }
  };

  // send the request
  const post = https.request(options, res => {
    // only respond once we're done, or Twilio's functions
    // may kill our execution before we finish.
    res.on("end", () => {
      // respond with an empty message
      callback(null, new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse());
    });
  });
  post.write(slackBody);
  post.end();
};
```

Comment: Why don't you simply acknowledge the POST with a `200` response and be done with it?

Comment: Because it's POSTing to slack, not a server that I'm controlling or have access to. I don't think slack allows you to provide responses to incoming webhooks, unless I'm msising something.

Comment: It's somewhat bizarre to be accepting HTTP requests without returning a response… But oh well, I have no idea about Slack, so I'll leave you to it…

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much how Twilio works with its webhooks. Once it receives a message, it just sends the details to a webhook and waits on a response. Just need to figure out if I can turn off this waiting process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio is always going to expect at least a 200 response or will timeout at 15 seconds for incoming message webhooks.

You could avoid the error messages by using something in between Twilio and Slack, like Zapier (example in [this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/09/connecting-sms-to-slack-with-twilio-and-zapier.html)) or using a Twilio Function (as [described here](https://medium.com/@emilong/how-to-receive-sms-in-slack-using-twilio-functions-4d65f0edc670)) or with Twilio Studio (from the [documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/how-to-post-sms-to-slack)).

Hope one of those ideas helps!

**Update**

Further to my earlier answer, and given the code you used to make the call, I have an update.

When making a request using Node's built in `https` module [you will not get the `end` event until you have read the data](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable). This is what is causing the timeout between Twilio and the Twilio Function, you are never responding to it because you don't consume the data from the request.

In a quick test I found that just listening for the `data` event meant that the `end` event did fire. So update your function to:

```
  const post = https.request(options, res => {
    // only respond once we're done, or Twilio's functions
    // may kill our execution before we finish.
    res.on("data", () => {});
    res.on("end", () => {
      // respond with an empty message
      callback(null, new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse());
    });
  });
```

And it should work.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using a Twilio function to send to slack, just as mentioned in that article, but that's what's generating the error. I guess I need to figure out how to make more changes to the function.

Comment: Hmm, can you share the code you're using in your function. I reckon there might be something there that's not behaving.

Comment: absolutely. Updated the original post to reflect the function.

Comment: Think I found what was going on, I updated my answer.